# laravel 5 vue setup unclear

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I've tried about everything now but I can't get vue.js to work on Laravel, there doesn't seem to be anything concrete around that says put x in file y to get it working.

I've tried about everything with npm, composer but i can't even get a basic example to work. It's very unclear to me what I need and where it needs to go.

I am using blade to extend from an app.layout view but it's unclear wether i need to add code to assets/js/app.js or just use script src="" tags in my default app layout.

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
});

var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
   data: {
     message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
   }  ,
   methods: {
     reverseMessage: function () {
      this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
   }
 })
```

app.layout.blade.php

```
<script src="{{asset('/js/app.js')}}"/></script>

..some more html

<body id="app">
   <div id="app-5">
   <p>@{{ message }}</p>
   <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
   </div>
   </body>

..more html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you define two Vue const?

this part of js code is no needed:

```
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
});
```

remove that line and test it :

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));



var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
   data: {
     message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
   }  ,
   methods: {
     reverseMessage: function () {
      this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
   }
 })
```

but remmember your vuejs work should be beetween:

```
<div id="app-5"> vuejs codes should be run here </div>
```

Don't forget running `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` to compile

if you have error and problem with this way you can skip to second way

---

**Second Way:**

create `vue-script.js` file in `public/js/` directory

vue-script.js:

```
var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   data: {
     message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
   }  ,
   methods: {
     reverseMessage: function () {
      this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
   }
 })
```

create `sample.blade.php` file in `resources/views/` directory

sample.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    @{{ message }}
    <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
  </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/vue-script.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

then in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('testvue', function() {
    return view('sample');
});
```

and go to url : `/testvue` in your browser

Comment: it still just displays {{ message }} as text

Comment: Are you running npm run watch or npm run dev to compile?

Comment: I get an error: npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`

Comment: @Florian  ok I update my answer with second way you can test it

Comment: Okay that worked. But I am still trying to use something like http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/ and it's not working.

Comment: you should use http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/#cdn , anyway if you have problem on that you should create a new question , and if this answer solved your question accept it as answer thanks

Comment: Either way, I thought you wouldn't need to use a cdn in laravel as vue.js would already be built in?

Comment: @Florian I recommend you to study https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix first and solve npm error then you could compile in import vue or other js and css files

Comment: I did actually fix the npm error, I just had to update my nodejs apparently.