# dropdowns and modals not working inside Vue components until I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am using Vue.js with Laravel 5.4
everything is working in the .blade.php files but not inside the .Vue files
nothing happens when I click on a dropdown or a modal button.
maybe I don't know what I'm doing but the weird thing that everything works fine when I refresh the page.

Any advice??

Comment: Any messages in the console? Can you share some code?

Comment: did you compile .vue files?

Comment: @RoyJ No messages in the console.

Comment: @Mohammadb I don't know how to compile a .vue file. I am still new to it, but I will google it

Comment: `npm run watch` watches `vue` files for updates, it doesn't watch blade files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Bulma CSS framework instead of bootstrap.

It provides a better integration with Vue.js.

Here is the link to the framework documentation:
[Bulma CSS framework documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/)
https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/

Comment: Just replaced the tags of bootstrap with the ones from Bulma and everything worked fine. you can check the documentation for how to make a dropdown or a modal using the Bulma

Answer (score 0):

[Writing Vue Components](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend#writing-vue-components)

you should run the `npm run dev` command each time you change a Vue component. Or, you may run the `npm run watch` command to monitor and automatically recompile your components each time they are modified

there is another way to use vue in your laravel that you can study it in this link : [laravel 5 vue setup unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881883/laravel-5-vue-setup-unclear/44882454#44882454)